# Unable to use limit_posts and post_url together

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Whenever I try to use the `limit_posts` flag to speed up the Jekyll build process `jekyll serve` complains that it can not find my posts which I link to with `post_url`.

This makes sense of course, if we limit the number of posts that we show it becomes impossible to link to them.

How do I fix this? Is it even possible to use `post_url` and `limit_posts` together like this?

```bash
$ bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload -o --incremental --limit_posts 1
Doing `require 'backports'` is deprecated and will not load any backport in the next major release.
Require just the needed backports instead, or 'backports/latest'.
Configuration file: C:/Users/JanMeppe/Documents/rainymood.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/JanMeppe/Documents/rainymood.github.io
       Destination: C:/Users/JanMeppe/Documents/rainymood.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: enabled
      Generating...
      Remote Theme: Using theme mmistakes/minimal-mistakes
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
  Liquid Exception: Could not find post "2019-08-04-regex-for-noobs" in tag 'post_url'. Make sure the post exists and the name is correct. in _pages/about.md
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Could not find post "2019-08-04-regex-for-noobs" in tag 'post_url'. Make sure the post exists and the name is correct.
```

Full code can be found here:

https://github.com/Rainymood/rainymood.github.io

Building on this commit specifically:

https://github.com/Rainymood/rainymood.github.io/commit/c25a109fb60926cc9af49d16c2cda843f5f6f871

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use post_url and limit_posts together, but the posts that you are linking to must be included in the limited set of posts that are generated.

What you could do for this:

- use the limit_posts flag with a higher value, such as `--limit_posts 10`, to ensure that the post is included
- specify the specific set of posts to include by using the `--include_posts` flag and listing the names of the posts that you want to include.

To specify the set of posts for `--include_posts`, pass a list of the post names, separated by commas:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload -o --incremental --include_posts post1.md,post2.md
```

You can also use wildcards:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload -o --incremental --include_posts _posts/*.md
```